# The project uses Gradle 2.12 which is incompatible with IDEA running on Java 10 or newer

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

When i import my Gradle Java project with `Intellij Idea` i get error

```
The project uses Gradle 2.12 which is incompatible with IDEA running on Java 10 or newer.
```

My Intellij Idea version is

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-192.5728.98, built on July 23, 2019
Runtime version: 1.8.0_211-b12 amd64
VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Linux 4.15.0-20-generic
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1956M
Cores: 4
Registry: git.explicit.commit.renames.prohibit.multiple.calls=false
Non-Bundled Plugins:
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Well, you will really have to upgrade Gradle to a newer version, e.g. Gradle 5.6.3.

Comment: Newer Gradle or older Java?

Comment: Will have to be newer Gradle, because IntelliJ will not run with that old a Java. Unless you use old IntelliJ also ;-)

Comment: Click on upgrade gradle link in Intellij error and select Use gradle from - 'wrapper task in gradle build script'! Works!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have found a solution for this. On Intellij press Ctrl+shift+a -> Switch Boot JDK ->choose JDK version 
[image]

Another solution is use Intellij Utimate Edition. Choose file/Setting and configure Gradle and Java version[image]

Answer (score 9):

In case if you didn't find switch boot JDK option in IDEA you can use
"choose runtime" plugin.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html

if you want it in action, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> 
then type choose runtime , in the dialog choose run time select the runtime you want.

[image]

Comment: I have searched for a solution for last 3 weeks, great thanks!
IntelliJ does not recommend to change runtime but sometimes it is needed when you facing unusual problems with build

Comment: Some of the latest IntelliJ e.g 2021 don't even run on JDK1.8. So need to choose lower version of IntelliJ

Answer (score 6):

On Intellij press Ctrl+shift+a -> Choose Runtime ->choose JDK version

If you don't see the option, then download and install "Choose Runtime"(https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12836-choose-runtime) from Marketplace
[image]

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains promised to fix in version 2020.1.1 : 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237220

Comment: I have Intellij IDEA version 2020.2 and the bug is still exists ))

Comment: I also have v2020.2 and the issue still persists.

Comment: still exists in 2022.1.4 as well : 'The project uses Gradle 2.14.1 which is incompatible with IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.4.'

Answer (score 0):

If IDEA still uses Java10 and above after startup, it is probably because IDEA comes with a higher version of Java. Solution: Rename the jbr directory in the IDEA installation directory.